# How to put a method in this app?

Tags: android, methods

i have the next code, and i want to put a method (i am newbie and don´t get how can i do that). Because when i am playing the sound and finish the app, this continue and can´t stop it, and if i put mp.pause(); before this finish(by Exit button) works, BUT if i NEVER pressed Play, my app don´t play the sound after this.
With methods i mean: if (SoundPlaying) mp.pause();

Code:

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
      adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rain);

    final ImageView Play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation Rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
                Play.startAnimation(Rotate);

            mp.start();

        }});


        final ImageView Pause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             mp.pause();
             Animation Rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
                Pause.startAnimation(Rotate);

            }});


        final ImageView Exit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        Exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                         MainActivity.this);

                 // Setting Dialog Title
                 alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to exit?");

                 // Setting Dialog Message
                 alertDialog.setMessage("If you liked the app, please Rate us!");

                 // Setting Icon to Dialog
                 alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.exit2);

                 // Setting Positive Yes Button
                 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                     int which) {
                                 // User pressed Yes button. Write Logic Here
                                finish();
                             }
                         });
                 // Setting Neutral Button
                 alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Rate us!",
                         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                     int which) {
                                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
                                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                    try {
                                        startActivity(goToMarket);
                                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn´t launch Google Play",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                             }
                         });
                 // Setting Positive "Cancel" Button
                 alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                     int which) {

                             }
                         });
                 // Showing Alert Message
                 alertDialog.show();

             }
         });

      //Orientación de la APP Vertical
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

}
```

Comment: You want to play sound with activty start and finish on exit?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh i want play sound when i click Play(button1 in code) and finish it, IF IS PLAYING when i press Yes(to exit) in the alertdialog.

Comment: If user click yes you want to stop it and if user click no you want to continue playing?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh exactly.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh is solved, but, anyway i want know. If you want help me to know/understand about methods please, i will love you :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "How do i implement an if statement" rather than method. You need to check if music is playing, and stop it if it is. Then once it has been stopped you can finish the activity.

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG that noob you are (?) Joke (:
Thanks man, lol, that easy, and i think that if was more complicated in Android D:

Answer (score 1):

When you are pausing sound after that write `int length = mp.getCurrentPosition();`

Like-

```
int length;
mp.pause();
length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
```

When user click no button write following code to continue playing from recent postion.

```
mp.seekTo(length);
mp.start();
```

And for yes button @Nood already answered.